# JavaScript If statement not operating correctly

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Below is my code and it always returns the IF statement as if it's false. Shouldn't it be true?

The variables asscostied with the IF statement:

```
var coloredUI = '';
var coloredText = '';
```

And here's the IF statement:

```
if (coloredText && coloredUI == '') {

} else {

}
```

Comment: Since both variables are strings then you should test for the contents of each string - as you have done with coloredUI variable.

Comment: @jeff, I didn't notice I couldn't compare two variables like so. Appreciate it.

Comment: @LeeTheCoder You actually can compare values as you did, but you need to understand what such syntax would be checking for. See my answer below for a full explanation of when that might actually be what you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, values can be "**truthy**" or "**falsy**". You set both your variables to empty strings, which are "falsy" (no characters == false). Other falsy values are:

**undefined**, **0**, **false**, **null**

An `if` statement always wants to test a condition for a truthy Boolean result. If you give it an expression, that expression is evaluated, and *if the result is not a Boolean, the JavaScript engine will coerce it into one*. Falsy values become false and truthy values become true, so:

```
 if(coloredText) {}
```

Evaluates to:

```
 if(false) {}
```

because `coloredText` was intialized to a falsy value (''). And because you used the short-circuited logical AND, both expressions would have to be true for the entire `if` to be true. But, since the first one was coerced to false, the `if` statement proceeds to the false branch.

To avoid this, you can write an expression that compares the expression rather than coerces it alone, as in:

```
 if(coloredText == '')  // true
```

This concept of implicit type coercion is also why **JavaScript provides two mechanisms for equality testing**. Take this for example:

```
 var x = 0;
 if(x == false)
```

This will result in `true` because **the double equal sign means equality with conversion**. The `false` is converted to a number (`0`) and then checked against the number (`0`), so we get `true`.

But this:

```
 var x = 0;
 if(x === false)
```

will result in a `false` result because **the triple equal sign means strict equality, where no conversion takes place** and the two values/expression are compared as is.

Getting back to your original scenario. **We leverage this implicit type coercion often when checking for feature support.** For example, older browsers don't have support for Geolocation (they don't implement the object that provides that feature). We can test for support like this:

```
 if(navigator.geolocation)
```

If the `navigator` object doesn't have a `geolocation` property, the expression will evaluate to `undefined` (falsy) and the `if` will head into its false branch. But, if the browser does support geolocation, then the expression will evaluate to an object reference (truthy) and we proceed into the true branch.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to explain why the IF statement had that output. Really informative, appreciate it!

Comment: Happy to help! ;)  Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

> Empty string(`''`) is `falsey` value

Following example will test whether both the values holds *truthy* values.

```js
var coloredUI = '';
var coloredText = '';
if (coloredText && coloredUI) {
  alert('if');
} else {
  alert('else');
}
```

**To test both values as `''`**

```js
var coloredUI = '';
var coloredText = '';
if (coloredText == '' && coloredUI == '') {
  alert('if');
} else {
  alert('else');
}
```

[**Truthy and Falsy Values**](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (coloredText  == '' && coloredUI == '') {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (coloredText == '' && coloredUI == '') {

} else {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if ((coloredText==='') && (coloredUI == '')){

} else {

}
```

OR if you want to check if there is a value in coloredText then use this:

```
if ((coloredText) && (coloredUI == '')){

} else {

}
```